# How to use Tradfri Lights with Ikea Tradfri Gateway within Alexa routines?

Tags: smart-home, alexa, amazon-echo, ikea-tradfri

I am using Echo Dots and the Tradfri Gateway and have seven Ikea Tradfri bulbs in two rooms. These bulbs show up under devices and can be put into groups, which work perfectly with Alexa voice commands.

I'm trying to create a **routine** using these bulbs that would involve turning on the TV/Stereo and dimming the lights.  The scene from my Harmony Hub for controlling the TV/Stereo works perfectly.  My problem comes from the bulbs.  They don't show up when I go to *Add Action* → *Smart Home* → *Control device*.  The only smart home device showing up is the Harmony Hub.

Since they are definitely detected by the app and on the device list, I'm wondering if anyone has a suggestion for how to get them to show up under routines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the app or firmware has been updated now.  It is working perfectly, using the process I described in the question (i.e. using *control devices*).